# In Flash IDE, how can I scale the contents of a symbol without affecting their appearance throughout the FLA?

Tags: flash, animation, bitmap

In Flash IDE I want to scale the contents of a symbol, and then inversely scale all the timeline instances of that symbol.

We have animations that were created at double the size of the intended final use size. Of course we can scale down the instances to 50%, but this is not what we want to do. And here is why.

Our use case for these animations involves converting some of the contents of the symbols to bitmap data for performance reasons. If we simply scale the instances down, the bitmap of the contents is still twice as large as needed.

Comment: Show your bitmap conversion code, you can pass in a matrix to scale the content when creating bitmap data

Comment: I want to do this in editor, not during runtime. I'm not using code, in that way. I'm using JSFL to call the built in command in Flash: Modify > Convert to Bitmap.